# Where should I call functions with side effects like Date.now or random?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

For example I need a current date or shuffle a list in reducer. Should I use effects for that?

```
 @Effect()
  foo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('Foo'),
    map(action => {
      //create result with Date.now or shuffle
      return {type: 'Foo_Result', payload: result}
    }

    )
  );
```

It feels like overkill. What is the best practice?

Comment: Have you considered calling `Date.now` in an action creator - so that the date value is part of the action's payload? Similarly, a shuffle action could include a random seed, etc.

Comment: @cartant I am not sure about this approach. There are already two places with logic, reducer and effects and action creators would be the third.

Comment: I would also put these inside action creators (these can be inpure).
But putting it inside an effect like your example isn't bothering it me.
Just don't do it in your reducers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is already provided in the comments but for the completeness let me provide a "real" answer here.

Like @cartant said, you can put these side effects inside an action creator. These action creators don't have to be pure, meaning you could so something like:

```
const addTodo = ({
    id = uuid(),
    description = '',
    createDate = Date.now
  } = {}) => ({
    type: 'ADD TODO',
    payload: { id, description, createDate }
  })
```

Doing this has an extra benefit, which is easier tests:

- In your action test, you test if the `id` and `createDate` is there but you dont test the values
- To test your reducer you can set these values, `addChat({id: 4654, description: 'a random todo', createDate: 111})`.

These are the reasons why I'm more in favor of doing this inside an action creator, you could do it inside an effect if you like but just don't do it inside the reducer functions.

**A reducer function must remain pure**.

For more info, I refer you to [Let’s have a chat about Actions and Action Creators within NgRx](https://blog.angularindepth.com/lets-have-a-chat-about-actions-and-action-creators-within-ngrx-41277ecc739d)